# Why JUnit 5 default access modifier changed to package-private

Tags: java, encapsulation, junit5, package-private

Why is the default access modifier in JUnit 5 package-private?

Tests in JUnit 4 had to be public.

What is the benefit of changing it to package-private?

Comment: ... You think that in JUnit5 tests declared as public won't work anymore?

Comment: The benefit is that you don't need to add `public` everywhere.

Comment: @Stultuske lol, no, I haven't written anything like this...

Answer (score 62, accepted):

> Why is the default access modifier in JUnit 5 package-private?

It's not the "default". There technically is no default. Rather, in JUnit Jupiter you have a choice: `public`, `protected` or package-private.

> What is the benefit of changing it to package-private?

The benefit is that you don't have type `public` anymore. If your IDE automatically generates test methods and test classes for you that are `public`, feel free to leave them `public`.

But... if you are typing in the methods on your own, then just leave off `public` unless you are designing your test classes for subclassing from other packages, in which case you'd want to make your *overrideable* test methods either `public` or `protected`. And of course, interface `default` methods must be `public`.

Long story, short: we (the JUnit 5 team) believe in the principle "Less is more", meaning the less you have to type to achieve your goal, the better!

Comment: I'd like to provide an alternative view: 
In this case less typing is also less expressiveness. When I make my tests public, I express the fact that the tests are exposed to an external caller (the test framework), just like I would do if I would write a library to be used by another application.
When using other access modifiers JUnit will have to use reflection to change them at runtime.
While it is technically possible to leave out the access modifier, I opt to explicitly add it. Adding public for me is the best way to expresses my intent to both JUnit and other developers.

Comment: what about our unit test class instance variables? Now that I am going down this road I want to start using the default modifier (<none>) on my mocks and other instance vars.

Comment: thank you. Jeezz! Was reading a JUnit 5 text and came across this statement: "package protected for test methods is preferrable as it leads to less typing" -- this made me think 'typing' used in the statement was referring to type casting or such-like. And I've been trying to understand the relationship expressed in the statement since a long time. But I'm really glad to meet your response.

Comment: I think this answer lacks the main point of - ***why***? yes, true, less is often more, and I believe it's not only you (JUnit team) who believes in that.. but the point is - why? and to be more precise - how? or, to elaborate a bit - why it was required until JUnit5 and why (what has changed) it's not in 5? was it just you asked "public" for no reason and now you've changed your mind? :)

Answer (score 5):

This is JUnit 5 [feature](https://github.com/junit-team/junit5/issues/679) which produce a better encapsulation for test classes and methods

> Make Jupiter tests package private #679

Test class mostly located in the [same package](https://sormuras.github.io/blog/2018-09-11-testing-in-the-modular-world.html) of the class tested:

> better way is to place the tests in a separate parallel directory structure with package alignment.
>
> ```
> main/                          test/
>    com/                           com/
>       xyz/                           xyz/
>           SomeClass.java               SomeClassTests.java
> ```
>
> This approach allows test code to access all the public and package visible members of the classes under test.

Comment: I'm not sure if this answers my question... I understand this is a feature and everything you've written is a general approach for all test frameworks. What is a benefit of having tests package-private, not public?

Comment: @wojtek1902 it produce a better encapsulation for test classes and methods

Comment: and what do I need encapsulation in tests for??

Comment: @wojtek1902 tests are still java code (although not executed in production)

Comment: It doesn't convince me, to be honest... I can't see any benefits from encapsulation in tests...

Comment: To quote Martin Fowler: `Test code is as important as production code. Give it the same level of care and attention. "this is only test code" is not a valid excuse to justify sloppy code` https://martinfowler.com/articles/practical-test-pyramid.html#WritingCleanTestCode